# How to assign the url of the uploaded photo from AWS to database(postgresql) model in the same endpoint

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-s3, fastapi

Below that there is an endpoint that uploads a photo to aws-s3 and return the url of the photo. This works well.

```
session1 = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id='XXXXXXXXXX',
    aws_secret_access_key='XXXXXXXXX'
)
S3_BUCKET_NAME = "XXXXX"
s3 = session1.resource("s3")
bucket = s3.Bucket(S3_BUCKET_NAME)

KB= 1024
MB = 1024 *KB


SUPPORTED_FILE_TYPES = {
    'image/png': 'png',
    'image/jpeg': 'jpg'
}

async def s3_upload(contents:bytes,key:str):
    logger.info(f'Uploading {key} to S3')
    bucket.put_object(Key=key, Body=contents)

async def s3_download(key=str):
    try :
        return s3.Object(bucket_name=S3_BUCKET_NAME,key=key).get()['Body'].read()
    except ClientError as err: 
        logger.error(str((err)))


router = APIRouter()



@router.post("/img-upload/")
async def upload(houseid:int,username:str,file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    if not file:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                            detail='No file found')
    contents= await file.read()
    size= len(contents)

    if not 0 < size <= 1 * MB:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                            detail='Suppoerted file size is 0-1MB')

    file_type = magic.from_buffer(buffer=contents,mime=True)

    if file_type not in SUPPORTED_FILE_TYPES:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                           detail=f'Unsupported file type: {file_type}. Supported types are {SUPPORTED_FILE_TYPES}'
                           )

    await s3_upload(contents=contents, key=f'{username}-{houseid}.{SUPPORTED_FILE_TYPES[file_type]}')
    uploaded_file_url = f"https://{S3_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com/{username}-{houseid}.{SUPPORTED_FILE_TYPES[file_type]}"
    return uploaded_file_url
```

What I want is that I want to save this url to database(Postgresql) inside of the /img-upload/ endpoint. I tried many methods but no solution yet.

I have a model as below. I want to assign the url from "/img-upload/" to img_url.How to do that?

```
class House(Base):
    id = Column(Integer,primary_key = True, index=True)
    title = Column(String,nullable= False)
    rent = Column(Integer,nullable = False)
    no_rooms = Column(Integer,nullable = False)
    size = Column(Integer,nullable = False)
    additional_cost = Column(Integer,nullable = False)
    total_rent = Column(Integer,nullable = False)
    max_flatmates = Column(Integer,nullable = False)
    exist_fmates = Column(Integer,nullable = False)
    heating_type = Column(String,nullable= False)
    heating_cost = Column(Integer,nullable = False)
    city = Column(String,nullable = False) 
    adress = Column(String,nullable = False)
    zipcode = Column(Integer,nullable = False)
    description = Column(String,nullable=False)
    min_duration = Column(Integer,nullable = False)
    smoking_allowed = Column(Boolean,nullable = False)
    parking = Column(String,nullable = False)
    postedby = Column(String,nullable = False)
    date_posted = Column(Date)
    img_url = Column(String,nullable = True)
    is_active = Column(Boolean(),default=True)
    owner_id =  Column(Integer,ForeignKey("user.id"))
    owner = relationship("User",back_populates="houses")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install the necessary drivers to connect to POSTGRESQL.

In Debian OS: `sudo apt-get install psycopg2`

2. `SQLAlchemy` engine is recommended.

`pip install sqlalchemy`

3. Use the SQLAlchemy to setup the database connection. Put this content inside a `database.py` file.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# Create a SQLAlchemy engine and session factory
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://your_username:your_password@your_host/your_database"
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

# Create a SQLAlchemy declarative base
Base = declarative_base()

# Dependency to get a database session for each request
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

4. Ensure the tables are created when the application starts:

```
from database import Base

@app.on_event("startup")
def startup():
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

5. Add this code to your endpoint:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from datetime import datetime

@router.post("/img-upload/")
async def upload(houseid:int,username:str,file: UploadFile = File(...), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    ### Your previous code
    uploaded_file_url = f"https://{S3_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com/{username}-{houseid}.{SUPPORTED_FILE_TYPES[file_type]}"
    
    # Inserting data in POSTGRESQL
    new_data = House(img_url=uploaded_file_url, date_posted=datetime.now(), is_active=True, owner_id=1)
    db.add(new_data)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(new_data)


    return uploaded_file_url
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Nuno.But I got an error when I used the code from you. I just changed a few things on your code and it works well now.

Here are the changes;

````
new_data.img_url = uploaded_file_url
db.add(new_data)
db.commit()
db.refresh(new_data)
return existing_house```
````